# Definition of an Upper Bound

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, upper-bound

The definition my professor gave us is: f(n) is O(g(n) for constant c > 0 and n<sub>0</sub> ≥ 0 where all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> and f(n) ≤ cg(n). I was wondering what n<sub>0</sub> and n are?

Example:
  for the function f(n) = an<sup>2</sup>+ bn + cn = (a+b+c)n<sup>2</sup>.
Assuming a,b,c were constants we can say: f(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>) where f(n) ≤ cn<sup>2</sup>.

What am I actually looking and to make sure that n<sub>0</sub> ≥ 0 where all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Let me write the definition in a little bit more detail.

> Suppose that $f(n),g(n)$ are two functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}_+$, that is, they accept as input a natural number, and return as output a positive real number.
>
> We say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$,
>
> $$ f(n) \leq Cg(n). $$

In order to show that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, you have to find $n_0$ and $C$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ it holds that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$. You can choose whatever $n_0,C$ you want as long as the condition holds. It turns out that for this definition, we can always take $n_0 = 1$ (for other variants of the definition, this no longer holds). So you only have to find a positive constant $C > 0$ such that for all $n \geq 1$ it holds that
$$ f(n) \leq Cg(n). $$
(This assumes that the first natural number is 1 rather than 0.)

Now we can answer your question:

- $n$ is the argument of the functions $f,g$.
- $n_0$ is the point beyond which the inequality $f(n) \leq C g(n)$ should hold. When proving that $f(n) = O(g(n))$, you get to choose $n_0$. In most cases you can just take $n_0 = 1$.

---

For the curious: why do we need $n_0$? Sometimes we would like to accommodate functions which are not strictly positive, but just eventually positive. For example, if 0 is a natural number (in contrast to the convention used above) then $n^2$ is not strictly positive, since it vanishes at $n = 0$. Therefore $n = O(n^2)$ is only true if we allow to "skip" $n = 0$, which we do by choosing $n_0 = 1$.

Comment: I don't totally agree with your 'for the curious' part. The $n_0$ is needed for the idea behind $\mathcal{O}$. If $f(n) \in{( \mathcal{O}(g(n))}$, then $g$ is growing at least as fast as $f$. So, from one point ($n_0$) $f(n) \leq{} Cg(n)$ must hold. But: it may be that$ f$ has a larger starting value. Simple example would be $f(n) = n² + 20$ vs. $g(n) = n³$. At the beginning ($n = 0$), $f$ is larger than $g$. But from one point $g$ 'outruns' $f$. And this will always happen, no matter how large the constant is, wich we add to $f$. It has nothing to do with positivity.

Comment: It turns out that if $g$ is always positive then $f(n) = O(g(n))$ iff there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for all natural $n$. Try it out in your example.

Comment: Never thought about that (and never learned it). But why is $n_0$ not just fixed as $1$ then? It would take away one variable and simplify everything.

Comment: For historical reasons. People just copy the definition from the textbook.

Comment: This is a great answer and I feel like I understand the subject matter now (can apply this to theta and omega now too). I honestly appreciate you for taking the time to answer. Thank you!